# Node.js application not executing in production env

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am new in node.js so unable to understand error properly. As per the sails document `https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/deployment`

I am trying to execute a sails.js application with `NODE_ENV=production node app.js` but it is throwing some errors. While it is working fine with for development environment with `npm run dev`

For now disabled session in my project. Now other warnings has been removed.

```
$ NODE_ENV=production node app
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error:
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
Warning: .tmp/public/js/sdk.js: 'with' in strict mode (22:780)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to resume watching for changes to assets:
error:      CTRL+C, then `sails lift`
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.
error: Troubleshooting tips:
error:
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and any custom Grunt plugins you're using installed in this project?
error:      Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error:
error:  *-> You might have a typo in one of your LESS files, etc.
error:
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `C:\xampp\htdocs\soochna_sails\.tmp` ?
error:
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME C:\xampp\htdocs\soochna_sails\.tmp
error:
error:  *-> If you're still unsure, drop by https://sailsjs.com/support.
```

my package.json file is

```
"description": "a Sails application",
    "keywords": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
        "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
        "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
        "async": "2.0.1",
        "grunt": "1.0.1",
        "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
        "sails": "^1.0.2",
        "sails-hook-autoreload-extend": "^1.0.4",
        "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.0.2",
        "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
        "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
        "sails-mysql": "1.0.0",
        "dropzone": "5.5.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production --ignore 'tmp/*' node app.js",
        "dev": "set NODE_ENV=development && nodemon --ignore 'tmp/*' app.js && exit 0",
        "test": "npm run lint && npm run custom-tests && echo 'Done.'",
        "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look good.'",
        "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo"
    },
    "main": "app.js",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git://github.com/xxxxxxx/test-project.git"
    },

    "license": "",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=9.11"
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it work fine in other environments like `development` ?

Comment: yes it is working fine with dev command "npm run dev"

Comment: Then try to fix those warnings first as recommended then what is that sdk ?

Comment: its a web application that I am trying to run with in production

Comment: its a web app I know but you can fix those warning

Comment: disabled session for now and updated log information in question. but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue aswell, quite a lot. This is the interesting part:

> error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
>   error:      e.g., `C:\xampp\htdocs\soochna_sails\.tmp` ?
>   error:
>   error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
>   error:      sudo chown -R YOUR_COMPUTER_USER_NAME C:\xampp\htdocs\soochna_sails.tmp

You are obviously hosting on windows, so try making the .tmp folder write accessible or delete it manually prior to launching your application in production mode.